# Copying a large amount of rows between two tables in two different mysql databases

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I've got a database, let's call it `Database A`, and another one called `Database B` in MySQL.

I have an SQL statement which picks up data from Database A (approximately 1 million rows) and need to insert them into Database B.

To read the data from Database A, I am using a `MySqlDataReader` which contains the 1 million rows.  I would now like to write them to Database B.

What I've tried doing is iterate through each row in the data reader, and write to the database with a simple INSERT stored procedure.  This is taking too long however.

I looked into the sql bulk data copy with C#, however I would not like to use external files.

What options do I have?

Comment: Look into SQL Bulk Data Copy without using external files?

Comment: Does it support it? Remember that this is MySQL. According to sources online, no mention is given to not using external files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple query like

```
 INSERT INTO mysqldb1.table1 SELECT * from mysqldb2.table2
```

This is executed all directly by the MySql engine avoiding any passage of data from MySql and your code

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO mysqldb1.table1 SELECT * from mysqldb2.table2";
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(.....))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
{
    cnn.Open();
    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
    Console.WriteLine(rows);
}
```

In a more complex scenario (for example, you need to repeat the operation and the target table initially doesn't exists) you could write a query like this

```
string cmdText = @"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mysqldb1.table1;
                   CREATE TABLE mysqldb1.table1 LIKE mysqldb2.table2;
                   INSERT INTO mysqldb1.table1 SELECT * from mysqldb2.table2";
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(.....))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this approach, however the insert is stopping after the first row. Do I need to specify the columns in the insert part, and do they need to be in a certain order?

Comment: It supposes that the source and destination table have the same schema. If not then you need to specify the columns matching in the insert and in the select

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Is there by any chance a way of returning how many rows were written?

Comment: The value returned by the ExecuteNonQuery is the count of the rows inserted/modified/deleted. It is your value.